# headjs multiple onready calls in IE8

Tags: javascript

Using IE8 and headjs

1. I have a template header template file that has a head.ready(function(){}) in it.  This page is loaded my all my pages.
2. On some page, I have scripts in the code that call the head.ready (which means it would be on the page twice because of the above header template).  I noticed that putting an additional head.ready(function(){}) works in Chrome/FF, however it appears not to work in IE8.  Only the first ready call seems to work.  The second one does not fire.

Does anyone know if this is an issue in IE8 and if there is a simple workaround?

Answer (score 0):

It might be an untested bug with IE8.

You'll probably have to poke at the source code which is never fun or try reporting it to the author.

Did you try any alternatives? YepNope? RequireJS? LabJS?

I wrote my own to be as small and simple as possible:

https://github.com/sgarbesi/fallback.js